# C# TCP client not sending data before closing

Tags: java, c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, tcp

I have created a Java TCP game server and listening on port 1990 for the new incoming connections.

I created a Unity3D client to connect to the server and send the message. The problem is that, I can connect successfully but when I try to send the message, it doesn't work until I close the socket. It somehow holds the sending of the data and sends it when socket is closed.

Unity C# client code:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1990);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.ReadTimeout = 10;
stream.WriteTimeout = 10;
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message From Client");
stream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
stream.Flush();
```

Java Server Code:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Server {

public static volatile Vector<User> usersList = new Vector<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1990);
    Socket socket = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    int i = 1;
    
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            socket = ss.accept();
            
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            
            // STARTING NEW DEDICATED THREAD
            User user = new User(i, socket.getInetAddress().toString(), socket, in, out);
            usersList.add(user);
            user.start();
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        i++;
    }
}
}

class User extends Thread {
    int uid = -1;
    int opponentUid = -1;
    String ipAddress = null;
    String data = null;
    Socket s;
    DataInputStream in;
    DataOutputStream out;
    User(int uid, String ipAddress, Socket s, DataInputStream in, DataOutputStream out) throws Exception
    {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.ipAddress = ipAddress.replace("/", "");
    this.s = s;
    this.in = in;
    this.out = out;
    
    String temp = null;
    while((temp = in.readLine()) != null) {
        data = temp;
    }
}

public void run()
{
    System.out.println("\nUser Id: " + uid + "\nIP Address: " + ipAddress + "\nData: " + data);
    try {
        out.writeUTF(String.valueOf(uid));
    } catch (Exception e1) { System.out.println("Client Error"); }
    
    while(true)
    {   
        try {
            String temp = null;
            while((temp = in.readLine()) != null) {
                data = temp;
                System.out.println("Client " + uid + ": " + data);
            }
            String[] vars = data.split("#");        // STRING SPLITTER TO GET THE DESTINATION IP
            if(vars[0].equals("matchmaking"))
            {
                for(User client : Server.usersList)
                {
                    if(client.opponentUid == -1 && client.uid != this.uid)
                    {
                        client.opponentUid = this.uid;
                        this.opponentUid = client.uid;
                        out.writeUTF("matched#" + String.valueOf(client.uid));
                        client.out.writeUTF("matched#" + String.valueOf(this.uid));
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(vars[0].equals("message"))
            {
                for(User client : Server.usersList)
                {
                    if(this.opponentUid == client.uid)
                    {
                        client.out.writeUTF(vars[1]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Client " + uid + " Disconnected");
            Server.usersList.remove((User)this);
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag Java?

Comment: Because the server is in java so maybe that'll put some hint for the problem.

Comment: The code in your question is C#. You didn't post the Java side of the code so the Java tag is unnecessary. Although, I don't know how you expect people to help without the server code.

Comment: Now I have added the server code also.

Comment: Things you I think you should do: 1.Use the connect function instead of the constructor of `TcpClient` to do the connection. 2.Show where/which function you are doing the connection from. You said it doesn't work until you close the socket but there is no close socket in your C# code.  What you have is simply not enough to help you. 3. find out if the server or the client is the problem by downloading *"Hercules SETUP utility"* and using it to test both your server and client code. This will save you so much time. Update your question with your discoveries

Comment: The server doesn't look like it is reading anything from the connection so it looks like the client isn't send, but it probably is.  Nothing in the server is calling run method.

Comment: @Programmer 1. I have tried the client with connect function also but nothing changed. 2. Whenever I close the socket means whenever I close the application, it sends the data. I have read somewhere on the internet that tcpclient stream is bidirectional in c# which means it listens and writes to the stream simultaneously thus, causes deadlock. I think that is the problem in my case so when I close the application/connection/socket/stream, it finally writes the data through the stream.